# Crontab executed php job that checks running php scripts is ignoring consecutive if statements

Tags: php, cron

I have this cron job

```
*/2 * * * * php /var/www/tests/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and cron.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/apache2/error.log');

$output = shell_exec('ps -C php -f');

if (strpos($output, 'php /var/www/html/testing/server.php') === false) { 
    shell_exec('php /var/www/html/testing/server.php > /var/log/apache2/websocket.log 2>&1');
    echo 'Run 1';
}

if (strpos($output, 'php /var/www/html/testing/server-ssl.php') === false) { 
    shell_exec('php /var/www/html/testing/server-ssl.php > /var/log/apache2/websocket.log 2>&1');
    echo 'Run 2';
}

if (strpos($output, 'php /var/www/html/testing2/server.php') === false) { 
    shell_exec('php /var/www/html/testing/server.php > /var/log/apache2/websocket.log 2>&1');
    echo 'Run 3';
}

if (strpos($output, 'php /var/www/html/testing2/server-ssl.php') === false) { 
    shell_exec('php /var/www/html/testing/server-ssl.php > /var/log/apache2/websocket.log 2>&1');
    echo 'Run 4';
}

?>
```

For some odd reason, the script only runs the first true if statement. So for example, if all four scripts are not running, the cron job will run cron.php and the first if statement will cause the first script to be run. 2 minutes later, the second will run, two minutes after that, the third will run, and so on.

Why are all four php scripts not run at the same time (given all are not running when the crontab executes cron.php)?

Comment: What do those scripts do? If the shell_exec command runs continuously, it will never complete, and thus never proceed to the rest of the script.

Comment: The scripts are websocket servers that should be running indefinitely. The main script (cron.php) is more of a watchdog so that if one of the servers dies, it is started again 2 minutes later. Or after a reboot, all scripts are automatically executed.

Comment: This is a job for supervisord, or if you don't want to set that up, plain 'ol bash. As @aynber said, you exec the first command, which ever returns, so...

Comment: You probably need to start the scripts  and send it to the background with `&`, so that shell_exec will return immediately.

Comment: Wow, you're right, `&` did it. Please add this as an anser so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, supervisord might be the best way to go about this, since it can easily monitor tasks and restart them as necessary. However, with this script, you can use `&` to send it to the background, so that shell_exec will return immediately and continue on.